# PDO Connection Pooling with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, time, pdo, connection-pooling

I have no idea how PDO's connection pooling works, and I'm getting nowhere with searches.

First, for clarity, is PDO's connection pooling automatic?

If not, how can I utilize it on an AJAX page?

I've clocked the time cost on my local wampserver dev of making a database connection via mysqli at 10ms per, and I'm trying to drive wait times as close to 0 as possible.  This is one of my last issues.

Comment: Also, database manages connection pools, not PDO.

Comment: If you are talking about persistent connections look here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Could you explain?  Is it just that mysqli doesn't use connection pooling?

Comment: afaik they are pooled on PHP site, if there is one it is used and the connection handshake isn't necessary. Afaik there is a timeout, but read yourself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about persistent connections look here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

> Do persistent connections remain open across different AJAX requests?

Yes and the risk that they are never reused. Thanks to @carefulnow. I'll quote his comments here:

> Persistent connections and connection pooling are not the same thing
> Connection pooling creates a lot of connections to start with, and then the application just grabs one of those already established connections. Persistent connections do establish new connections, but they do not close unless explicitly told to (a normal connection will close at the end of the script). Persistent connections are dangerous if not used carefully, as most databases implement a maximum connections count, and will refuse further connections when hit. For most cases, a normal connection (just calling the PDO constructor with a DSN and login details) will be fine.
>
> I'll explain it by showing the PHP code, and the resulting connection count in the MariaDB console monitor. Look at the following screenshots, and pay attention the the "run count" in the bottom right. You'll see when using persistent connections, connections do not close, but instead go into sleep mode. Ignore connection #231, that's the console monitor's.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkCjN.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXaGQ.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUlGA.png. As you can see, the time column indicates the length of inactivity, not the length of time connected, hence the console monitor's time is always zero, because I've just executed SHOW PROCESSLIST;. I hope this clears everything up a bit, database connection management is quite tricky sometimes.

So looking at the screenshots the questions is open, how to pickup these persistent connections again. Some answers on StackOverflow say, that they are cached on thread level, so if you have more than one thread (which is highly expected) than you get many connections. This opens the risk to run into the connection limit of mysql. Before using persistant connections make sure you understand how they work (which I don't, but it seems @carefulnow :-))

> Is it possible to set a persistent connection to expire?

PHP doc says they are cached, therefore I assume they are cleanup after a time.

[More on the php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)

Comment: Persistent connections and connection pooling **are not the same thing!!!**

Comment: @carefulnow thanks for the comment. What is the difference?

Comment: Connection pooling creates a lot of connections to start with, and then the application just grabs one of those already established connections. Persistent connections do establish new connections, but they do not close unless explicitly told to (a normal connection will close at the end of the script). Persistent connections are dangerous if not used carefully, as most databases implement a maximum connections count, and will refuse further connections when hit. For most cases, a normal connection (just calling the PDO constructor with a DSN and login details) will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. What happens with persistant connections? Are they not pooled? So after the script ran, they are kept open, and never picked up again? Or is the "only" difference pooling means persistant connections opened in the beginning and peristant connections are pooled, when they are needed?

Comment: I'll explain it by showing the PHP code, and the resulting connection count in the MariaDB console monitor. Look at the following screenshots, and pay attention the the "run count" in the bottom right. You'll see when using persistent connections, connections do not close, but instead go into sleep mode. Ignore connection #231, that's the console monitor's. http://i.imgur.com/IL42tjF.png, http://i.imgur.com/aDvl7F7.png, http://i.imgur.com/IuFEEvO.png. As you can see, the time column indicates the length of inactivity, not the length of time connected, hence the console monitor's time is alw...

Comment: ...ays zero, because I've just executed SHOW PROCESSLIST;. I hope this clears everything up a bit, database connection management is quite tricky sometimes.

Comment: Updated the post a bit - if you have further critics, please tell me or update the post. Thanks for your time and the info!

Answer (score 3):

also on the same [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) given by @fabian you can see the following:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
?>

Note: If you wish to use persistent connections, you must set PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT in the array of driver options passed to the PDO constructor. If setting this attribute with PDO::setAttribute() after instantiation of the object, the driver will not use persistent connections.
```

Answer (score 0):

Pdo persistent uses the any URL with multiple mysql request as one connection. If the page reloaded or access any other php page with pdo connection makes only the new pdo connection. We need the static SQL connection already created in the server and reuse it for the pages. Like global declaration before the page load. It only possible with node mysql package with express. In express js we can configure the mysql pool connection as global declaration.

You can use the connection pooling in nodejs with mysql and express npm modules . And setup a http server in node, then make the request to express server via **API** like http://127.0.0.1:1000/getdata in a post request. Then use the php as the getter using the file() method with stream context for creating the post request. Don't use curl because it takes more time for the execution. Use while statement for check the data return from the express js server

This post I created via mobile, so I can't give the explained code for the use. If anyone need the example code. I'll post to the GitHub repo. Share your comments